# Username being truncated on MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, meta, winter-bash-2012

Something that changed today (perhaps Winter Bash) is causing my username to be shortened at the top of the page but *only* on MSO.

When the page loads, it is correct but almost instantly it gets truncated.

**Before**:

[image: before]

**After** a split second:

[image: after]

Note: Stack Overflow and Programmers does not do this.

Comment: Are you by chance using Opera?

Comment: @Aarthi I am using Chrome.

Comment: Is it the most recent version of Chrome?

Comment: @Aarthi "Google Chrome is up to date."

Comment: Blame the hats!

Comment: It is the Winter Bash script, although I'm not sure why it's doing the shortening it's doing.

Comment: Blame Chrome/WebKit! (Now that is *even more* fun.)

Comment: Its Hats, Hats and Hats all over MSO ... :P

Comment: ...and mad hatters ? :-)

Comment: WinterBash is definitely the culprit here. I wrote some js to measure the exact number of available pixels, and truncate your display name accordingly. Clearly, it's not working correctly here... I'll look into it.

Comment: @Emmett but I have longer display name, using Chrome as well, and it doesn't happen here.

Comment: @Emmett: I see it in Chrome on Windows 7 on a 1280x800 display. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159239/with-winter-bash-my-name-is-abbreviated-on-meta) (now closed as a duplicate).

Comment: @KeithThompson The resolution doesn't seem to have anything to do with it. It is the same on all of my machines.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this.. since we're all devs here: if you're getting excessive truncation, can you please report what you're getting for these 5 values (by typing them into Chrome's console): (a) `$('#portalLink').offset().left` (b) `$('#portalLink').outerWidth()` (c) `$('#portalLink').outerWidth(true)` (d) `$('#hlinks-nav').offset().left` (e) `$('#hlinks-user').outerWidth(true)`

Comment: @Emmett This is on a different machine but same issue. The results: (a) 226 (b) 120 (c) 114 (d) 663 (e) 151

Comment: @Austin thanks a lot; pushing a fix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

To make room for the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) logo in the nav, I wrote some javascript to measure the available width for your display name, in pixels, and truncate the display name if necessary. But it didn't work correctly for lowish-rep users, or more specifically, users for whom `$('#hlinks-nav')` is empty.

Comment: So really, [meta-tag:status-bydesign]: earn more reps.

Comment: It wasn't a problem on Programmers and I am even lower rep on there.