# Winter Bash username doesn't display special HTML character

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012, encoding

The page header shows `DavRob60&#39;s Holiday Season User` instead of `DavRob60's Holiday Season User`:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in order to check it , we have to change our Display name... :D

Comment: Hats seem to be wrecking havoc [everywhere!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159177/169404)

Comment: same to me and also about #39. Perhaps that only happens with apostrophes or any other SGML entity would show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed now! Thanks for the report.

Comment: But it is not fixed [everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159248/187824) :(