# URL escaping shown for Lego in hats pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

See here for an example, http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/bricks.stackexchange.com
LEGO® Answers appears as `LEGO&#174; Answers` (same in a few places where that is displayed.)

Comment: Related : [Winter Bash username don't display special HTML character](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159193/187824)

Comment: Note that the above is marked complete but it's not fixed everywhere, only where it was mentioned in the question.

Comment: @hims056 It's not exactly related as that's been fixed. Cheers for raising this for us - was doing exactly the same ;)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - Updated the comment. And this is not duplicate because you are asking for Site name.

Comment: @Emmett there are still some places where it's still happening :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Sadly it's not fixed Emmett - please see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159858/33051) for details of other locations where the issue is still occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it's not completely fixed - and I wish I hadn't deleted my duplicate answer, because if you don't display every single instance of where it's happening the issue doesn't get fixed...

[image: On the Home page]

On the home page when you click on a hat you've earned on LEGO Answers, it still appears with the encoding in the title, rather than the ® symbol.

Comment: Didn't spot that otherwise I'd have added it to the original question. Well spotted!

Comment: Yeah, that was my poor attempt at an edit yesterday ;)